# Rendered image has WEIRD AND GRAINY lighting

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadows

I'm trying to make an animation inside Freddy Fazbear's Pizza, but when I rendered the image to see how it looked, I got THIS.[image: The rendered image]

I don't know how the heck this happened. for reference, this is what it looked like before the render.
[image: Before the render]

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like having overlapping objects?

Comment: Duplicated geometry causing z-fighting.